# Output nearby primes

Tags: code-golf, number, primes

Write a program which takes an input (which may or may not be prime), and lists the immediate prime following and preceding it.

**Example input:**

```
1259
```

**Example output:**

```
1249 1277
```

Shortest program wins. Must execute within 10 seconds on a modern desktop PC. Inputs will be limited to 10,000 maximum.

Comment: It seems somewhat odd to list a time limit without also limiting the range of possible inputs. Are we required to find several-thousand-digit primes within ten seconds?

Comment: @Anon. Assume I will not give ridiculous inputs, but the program must be somewhat optimised. I have clarified the question text.

Comment: my one-liner is anything but optimal, but it runs in ~1s for an input of 10000. You have to try really hard to need 10s.

Comment: @ninjalj Just to weed out absolutely awful algorithms.

Comment: so you don't consider testing a number `n` for primality  by creating a string `n` characters long and testing that against a regex absolutely awful?

Comment: 10k isn't a reasonable limit, combined with 10s.

Comment: May we assume that the input is at least 3, so that the "preceding prime" is defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Perl 5.10 (perl -E), 65 chars

Half the credit (at least) should go to @J B.

```
$m=<>;for(-1,1){$n=$m;0while(1x($n+=$_))=~/^1$|(^11+)\1+$/;say$n}
```

Comment: nice! the prime test regex!

Comment: yeah, I learned about it  at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543811/code-golf-happy-primes

Comment: Seems like you could save a couple of characters with a quoted regex (+2 for the `qr`, -4 for not needing the delimiters later).

Comment: Actually, it works without `qr`.  LMGTFY: 81 chars `$m=$n=<>;$p='^1$|(^11+)\1+$';0while(1x--$m)=~$p;0while(1x++$n)=~$p;print"$m $n$/"`

Comment: Second round, factoring both pattern matches (66 chars): `perl -E'$m=<>;for(-1,1){$n=$m;0while(1x($n+=$_))=~q<^1$|(^11+)\1+$>;say$n}'`

Answer (score 15):

### *Mathematica*, 19

```
#~NextPrime~{-1,1}&
```

Comment: very clever :0)

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica: 28 chars

```
(k=NextPrime;{k[#,-1],k@#})&
```

Usage

```
%[1259]
{1249, 1277}  

%[121231313159]  
{121231313129, 121231313191}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python - 93

Based on [answer by fR0DDY](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/632/output-nearby-primes/643#643). I basically merged lines 4 and 5, and shortened line 2 by using a different method.

```
n=input()-1
m=n+2
f=lambda n:any(n%x<1for x in range(2,n))
exec"n-=f(n);m+=f(m);"*m
print n,m
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 22 characters

```
(_4&p:,4&p:)(".stdin)_
```

Comment: 9 years old but hey... :) `_4 4 p:"+`

Answer (score 3):

**Python <s>116</s> <s>111</s> 109 Characters**

```
n=input()-1
m=n+2
f=lambda n:any(pow(b,n-1,n)>1for b in(3,5,7,13))
while f(n):n-=1
while f(m):m+=1
print n,m
```

Comment: use `f=lambda n:not(all(pow(b,n-1,n)<2for b in(3,5,7,13)))`

Comment: @fR0DDY, instead of the first 3 lines use `n=input()-1` and `m=n+2`, saves 3 chars...i think.

Comment: and maybe you can replace `not(all(...))` by `any(...)` reversing the booleans

Comment: You don't count new lines. Actual count is `108`.

Comment: @fR0DDY Please don't list all your intermediate solutions as they're viewable in the edit history if anyone wants to see them.

Comment: Also, please count newlines in your character count. -1 for deceiving others.

Comment: After you've fixed your count you can try replacing line 2 with `f=lambda n:not all(n%x for x in range(2,n))` and lines 3 and 4 with: `exec"n-=f(n);m+=f(m);"*m`

Comment: I paste the code in Ideone and copy the characteres count from there. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Æp,Æn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW4HO4ba8////GxqZWgIA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 bytes

```apl
¯4 4⍭⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//9B6EwWTR71rH3Ut@p/2qG3Co96@R13Nj3rXPOrdcmi98aO2iY/6pgYHOQPJEA/P4P9pCoZGppYA)

I wish I knew a way to shorten this further.

`¯4` and `4` when passed to `⍭` give the closest primes to the right argument(`⊢`).

Answer (score 2):

## Swift <s>190</s> <s>187</s> <s>185</s> 110

Swift is very bad in code-golf, but I tried it anyway :D
It's getting shorter and shorter...(Thanks to [@HermanLauenstein](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70894/herman-lauenstein) for removing 75 bytes)

```swift
var a=Int(readLine()!)!;for b in[-1,1]{var n=a,c=0;while c<1{n+=b;c=1;for i in 2..<n{if n%i<1{c=0}}};print(n)}
```

Comment: -75 bytes with a lot of restructuring `var a=Int(readLine()!)!;for b in[-1,1]{var n=a,c=0;while c<1{n+=b;c=1;for i in 2..<n{if n%i<1{c=0}}};print(n)}` (I haven't tested it properly yet)

Comment: Thanks @HermanLauenstein. It's my first code-golf, so I can need every help :)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell: 99

```
s(z:y)=z:s[x|x<-y,mod x z>0];f(x:y:z:w)=(x,z):f(y:z:w);p x=(head.filter(\(c,v)->c<x&&v>x).f.s)[2..]
```

Example

```
Main> p 1259
(1249,1277)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 116 <strike>139</strike> chars (double indent is tab-char)**

Uses good ole Sieve of Eratosthenes

**Edits** and (thanks a TON @JPvdMerwe). Should work with primes now.

```
l=n=input();a=range(n*2)
for i in a[2:]:a=[k for k in a if k==i or k%i]
for g in a:
 if g>n:print l,g;break
 if i!=n:l=g
```

**Original**

```
a=range(9999)
j=lambda a,n:[i for i in a if i==n or i%n]
for i in a[2:]:a=j(a,i)
o=n=input();
for i in a:
 if o<n and i>n: 
  print o,i
 o=i
```

Comment: -1 For not counting **NECESSARY** white space.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe My fault, I'm new here, and I realized I may have used the wrong metric from my editor.

Comment: @JPvDMerwe also thanks for the help on the edits

Comment: @DougT cool everyone makes a mistake :) +1 To reverse my down vote, just make sure next time.

Comment: One trick you can do is to move lines 1-3 below line 4 and replace `a=range(9999)` with `a=range(n)`. Also in line 2 you don't need to pass `a` to the lambda, you can just use it. This should shave off a lot.

Comment: Also I just realised this doesn't work if `n` is a prime.

Comment: Thinking some more, you can use: `for i in a[2:]:a=[j for j in a if j==i or j%i]` To get rid of that long lambda.

Comment: Playing around you need `a=range(n*2)`

Comment: You didn't count line breaks, real tally is `120`. Use: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/charcount.shtml but make sure that you don't have an extra new line at the end.

Comment: Then there are 2 things you can still do: `break` -> `n*=n` and `i!=n` -> `l<n`

Comment: But your solution does not run within 10 seconds for 9900 as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 119:

```
def p(n:Int)=(2 to n-1).exists(n%_==0)
def i(n:Int,v:Int):Int=if(!p(n+v))n+v else i(n+v,v)
Seq(-1,1).map(i(readInt,_))
```

ungolfed:

```
def notPrime (n:Int) = 
    (2 to n-1).exists (n % _ == 0)

def itPrime (n: Int, vector:Int) : Int =
    if (! notPrime (n+vector)) n+vector
    else itPrime (n+vector, vector)

def nearbyPrime (value: Int) =
    Seq (-1, 1).map (sign => itPrime (value, sign))
```

21.2s to run **all** 9998 ints from 3 to 10.000

Answer (score 0):

### Python (123)

```
import Primes as p
j=i=int(input())
n=p.primes(i*2)
while not i in n[:]:
 i+=1
print(i)
while not j in n[:]:
 j-=1
print(j)
```

**NOTE: The `Primes` module was written by me but it existed before this question was asked.  It was NOT written for this.  Nevertheless, this was deemed unfair, so here is the updated version.**

### Python(215)

```
j=i=int(input())
import math as m
s=list(range(i*2))
for n in s[:]:
 for l in range(1,int(m.ceil(m.sqrt(n)))):
  if(n%l)==0and l!=1and n in s:s.remove(n)
while not i in s:i+=1
print(i)
while not j in s:j-=1
print(j)
```

Comment: I don't know how you managed to get your count wrong but it's actually: `123`

Comment: Also, @John unless the module is now part of the language, in the interest of fairness you should include the code. But Kudos on the honesty.

Comment: I think it cheating to use `Primes`; against the spirit of code golf.

Comment: @JPv: Huh.  It *was* wrong.  I wonder how that happened.

Comment: @Thomas, @JPv: I have posted an updated version without the import.

Comment: @John you can remove a lot of white space by moving the `i+=1` for example to the same line as the `while`. Similarly for the last `if`. And it makes sense to merge the 2 `if`s.

Comment: @JPv: Ah, right.  Thanks.  That was done in a hurry so I didn't have time to think about it much.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
èëïy▌Ü╚
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8a898b79dd9ac8&i=1259)

ASCII equivalent:

```
^:Px:pLJ
```

Built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,d)=>d?p(n)?n:f(n+d,d):[f(n-1,-1),f(n+1,1)]
p=(n,i=1)=>++i*i>n||n%i&&p(n,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctBCoMwEIXhvfeoZpooTGiJEaIHKQXFaInIJNTSlXdPk2V3j4//bdN3Oua3C5@avF1iXA0jYcH0dgiMYKBuZcRtou6RVo2iRhDZUCA8i5B7ZzA9OHdX19N50sWVZcgOcfZ0@H1pdv9iK0N519Bs3tEoRmMqlDctUCpVQfFfat0qgPgD)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>98</s> <s>89</s> 87 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
N,i;g(n,d){for(i=N=n+=d;--i>1;)N*=N%i>0;N?printf("%d ",n):g(n,d);}f(n){g(n,-1);g(n,1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99PJ9M6XSNPJ0WzOi2/SCPT1s82T9s2xVpXN9PO0FrTT8vWTzXTzsDaz76gKDOvJE1DSTVFQUknT9MKosu6Nk0jT7MaxNE11AQbBaRq/wPVKuQmZuZpAM3VMDQytQQJAgA)

## Full program version, [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>116</s> <s>107</s> 105 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
N,i;g(n,d){for(i=N=n+=d;--i>1;)N*=N%i>0;N?printf("%d ",n):g(n,d);}main(n){scanf("%d",&n);g(n,-1);g(n,1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99PJ9M6XSNPJ0WzOi2/SCPT1s82T9s2xVpXN9PO0FrTT8vWTzXTzsDaz76gKDOvJE1DSTVFQUknT9MKosu6NjcxM08jT7O6ODkxDyytpKOWpwk2VNcQQgOp2v//DY1MLQE)

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [22 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
ét█ï▀¢│B¬Ÿ6├¼òa¡b←Æ╚ÑÕ
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=azooKHY6Iy5eMik6aSlbdj8tLWsgdj8oaysy&input=MTI1OQ==)

## Explained

Unpacked: `k:((v:#.^2):i)[v?--k v?(k+2`

One of the major weaknesses of Arn (along with operator precedence lmao)

```
  :                     Assign variable
k                       with name of k
    (                   Begin expression
        (
            :
          v
              #.        List of primes from 0 to
                  _     Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
                ^       exponentiated by
                  2     Literal two
        )               End expression
      :i                Index of
        _               implied
    )
[                       Begin sequence
    v
  ?                     Indexed by
    --k                 k minus 1
    v
  ?
    (
        k
      +                 Plus
        2
    )                   implied
]                       End of sequence; implied
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ÅMsÅN»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKtv8eFWv0O7//83NDK1BAA)

```
ÅMsÅN»  # full program
     »  # join...
ÅM      # nearest prime less than...
        # implicit input...
     »  # with...
   ÅN   # nearest prime greater than...
  s     # implicit input...
     »  # by a newline
        # implicit output
```